# How can I \ref different tables in the appendix?

Tags: longtable

I need to \ref first and second long table into different part of the main text, but when I type \ref, it shows only one {long}, the main text shows the same number of the table. What can I do?

Comment: as you show no code it is impossible to guess what you have done wrong. if the first table has `\label{red}` and the second `\label{blue}` then you can use `\ref{red}` and `\ref{blue}` to reference them

Comment: Oh, thank you, this helps. I named the same label.

Comment: you must have got an error  from a re-used label, never ignore error messages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is solved. I did not rename the table into a different name.